# How to convert string to clob?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, clob, sql-navigator

I have procedure

```
PROCEDURE test_proc (text IN Clob) as
Begin
  insert into table_name values(SYSDATE,xmltype.createxml(text));
end ;
```

And I run

```
begin
  test_proc('.....text...');
end;
```

Length of the text is 64.8 KB

erorr: PLS-00172:string literal too long

But, If I insert the text into Value/Expresion (SQL Navigator 6.7.0 Relase) and execute the procedure -> PL/SQL block executed

Comment: What is the create script for your table? Running the code with table `CREATE TABLE table_name (when DATE, content XMLTYPE);` I get `ORA-31011: XML parsing failed` which is normal.

Comment: CREATE TABLE table_name (
   date_rep  DATE,
   save_rep XMLTYPE)
   XMLTYPE save_rep STORE AS OBJECT RELATIONAL
      XMLSCHEMA "name_schema.xsd"
      ELEMENT "name_element"; ,  where name_schema.xsd is DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema

Comment: Maximum varchar2 is 32K.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the conversion, the problem is with your string literal. It is too big for the Oracle SQL parser to handle.

Maybe load the CLOB from a file instead?

Comment: But, If I insert the text into SQL Navigator 6.7.0 Relase and execute the procedure -> PL/SQL block executed